# How can I count all the NULL values in all columns in a sqllite table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I don't want to write a large query statement like

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0),
       SUM(CASE WHEN column2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0),
       SUM(CASE WHEN column2 IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0),
....
FROM Table
```

Because there are almost 200 columns.
And the result should show the amount of NULL distinct by column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply like over all columns without specifying all column names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815025/apply-like-over-all-columns-without-specifying-all-column-names)

Comment: @hakamairi That's for SQL server, not sqlite or MySQL. OP: which database are you using? Only tag that one instead of multiple different ones.

Comment: @Shawn, general approach would be exactly the same, right?

Comment: @hakamairi I think there are some differences between the two questions. The older question didn't solve my problem.Because what I am concerned is avoid writing a large SUM(...) statement.

Comment: @hakamairi Since most of the decent answers there involve things like stored procedures, no.

Comment: @Shawn interesting, stored procedures actually might be the way (taking into account sqlite limitations those can be user defined function like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24229785/sqlite-net-sqlitefunction-not-working-in-linq-to-sql/26155359#26155359). Lets see where it goes.

Comment: Just use a query or spreadsheet to write the query.  The metadata tables have all the column names for the table.