# LIKE in any column from the table

Tags: sql, impala

I have a table that contains more than 300 columns. Some of the column names are generated dynamically each day. Any of these columns may contain a specific string.

Is there any way to build a LIKE statement (or similar) that can search through all columns?

Table looks something like this:

```
id  column_random_name_1 column_random_name_2 column_random_name_3
1   abc                  lkj                  ipx_my_string_ipx
2   bcd                  jhd                  jug
3   hjf_my_string_hjf    pod                  asx
4   pol                  jik_my_string_jik    mlp
5   hgh                  dop                  btx
```

The expected resultset would contain only the rows that contain *'*my_string*'* in any column:

```
id  column_random_name_1 column_random_name_2 column_random_name_3
1   abc                  lkj                  ipx_my_string_ipx
3   hjf_my_string_hjf    pod                  asx
4   pol                  jik_my_string_jik    mlp
```

Comment: You may check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8815227/5321202

Comment: Sounds like a horrible situation with 300 columns, changing from day to day. Why? A 300 column LIKE will perform lousy.

Comment: you can use `col1 like 'x' or col2 like 'x'... ` but perf will be horrible.  You can also use spark(pyspark) may be to make it faster. Now, if you have dynamic col name, it will make solution difficult and spark will be your only option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a dynamic query

1. Get all lists of columns from the table
2. build like query on the basis of table and columns

   CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SearchTable
   @tablename NVARCHAR(257),
   @term      NVARCHAR(4000)
   AS
   BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   ```
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM ' + @tablename + ' WHERE 1 = 0'; 

    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' 
      OR ' + c.name + ' LIKE ''%' + REPLACE(@term, '''', '''''') + '%'''
    FROM 
      sys.all_columns AS c
    INNER JOIN 
      sys.types AS t
      ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
      AND c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
    WHERE 
      c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@tablename)
      AND t.name IN (N'sysname', N'char', N'nchar', 
        N'varchar', N'nvarchar', N'text', N'ntext');

    PRINT @sql;

    -- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
   ```

   END
   GO

Comment: i dont think this is how hive will work. This is for MS SQL i feel.